# Using synergy between mac os x and ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mac, synergy

I tried to get synergy working, here is the step that I have done:

1. Installing quick synergy in Ubuntu
2. Installing synergykm in mac os x
3. Using IP address instead of hostname
4. Using synergyc / synergys

The problem is, it keep giving connection timed out, and when I checked using telnet from Ubuntu `myMacIpAddress 24800`,  It said that connection refused.

When I tried from Mac OS X `telnet myUbuntuIpAddress 24800`, it said that connection is timed out, does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: looks like firewall's blocking the ports

Comment: Are you using Lion on the OS X computer? Last time I checked a couple months back there were a lot problems using Synergy with Lion.

Comment: using OS X lion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it turn out, somehow when I tried to ping my ubuntu from my mac it gave me destination host unreached. so after a little bit tinkering ,change the ip address of both computer and make sure that both can ping each other and viola, it worked. synergy that i used is the latest version using mac lion and ubuntu 12.04

so summary:

1. make sure that your mac and ubuntu understand each other that is can ping each other
2. using the latest version of synergy
3. synergy version for both ubuntu and mac MUST BE the SAME